# ImportError: cannot import name get_sorted_tuples

Tags: python

There are two files in same directory.

The first file is `parser.py`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import csv
import json
import requests
import time
from collections import defaultdict

def load_matrices():
    # code...
def get_sorted_tuples(matrix, country, code_to_name, size=20):
    # code...
```

The second is `b.py`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import json
from geojsontosvg import lolatoxy
from parser import get_sorted_tuples, load_matrices
import math
```

When I run `b.py`, I get this error:

```
from parser import get_sorted_tuples, load_matrices
ImportError: cannot import name get_sorted_tuples
```

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Are you able to do `import parser`?

Comment: when I change `from parser import get_sorted_tuples, load_matrices` to `import parser`  the error became like this `NameError: name 'load_matrices' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that Python has a module named [`parser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/parser.html) in standard library, and that's what you're actually trying to import from. You have two options:

- Rename `parser.py` to something else.
- If both files are inside a package, do relative import in `b.py`:

```py
from .parser import get_sorted_tuples, load_matrices
```